# What makes an Android application vulnerable to Cross-site scripting (XSS)?

Tags: exploit, xss, mobile, android, java

**Definition of XSS**

If you search the web, there are many different ways to define a cross site scripting attack. Simply put, XSS vulnerabilities occur when a malicious attacker is permitted to inject a client-side script into a web site that is viewed by other people who become the victims of the attack.

**An example of an XSS bug within Android O.S**

> *Vulnerability Details*
>
> By sending a crafted intent to Chrome for Android, malicious Android
>   apps can inject JavaScript: URIs into arbitrary Web pages loaded in
>   Chrome. Injected JavaScript works in the context of the target Web
>   page's domain, not a blank domain. So it can be used for Cookie theft
>   or so. Such kind of vulnerabilities is often called Cross-Application
>   Scripting.
>
> *Version*
>
> Chrome Version: Chrome for Android v18.0.1025123 Operating System:
>   confirmed on Android 4.0.4 (Samsung Galaxy Nexus)
>
> *Reproduction Case*
>
> A sample code of a malicious Android app is attached.
>
> *Note*
>
> This issue was initially reported to security@google.com on Jul. 7
>   2012, but recently I heard from Google security team that the issue
>   might not be filed in Chromium bug database. So now I re-submit the
>   issue here which should be a legitimate place for reporting Chrome
>   bugs.

**My Question**

Although I understand *what Cross-Site-Scripting is* and *how Cross-Site-Scripting can take place*. I don't know **what factors makes a selection of Android code vulnerable to such an attack.**

Comment: While I appreciate that you split this from your other question on SQL (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89897/what-makes-an-android-application-vulnerable-to-sql-injection) it is odd that it is basically the same question. Is there a common cause or reason for these questions?

Comment: To be blunt, they are different types of vulnerability. And I'd like to learn as much as I can. Hence why I've been as specific as possible. (Also, the questions aren't identical)

Comment: "what factors makes a selection of Android code vulnerable to such an attack" is repeated in all 3

Comment: One line out of an entire different question, with different content and focus

Comment: if you asked one (like your SQLi question) you might find that there is a common factor that relates to all - that way you reduce the mesh of questions

Comment: I'm trying to help you get the answers you seek - I'm not trying to give you a hard time - what you've done so far has increased the risk of your questions getting closed

Comment: the common thread to your questions is that Android itself is not the problem - the programs/apps/services run by Android are the ones vulnerable

Comment: I don't understand what I should have done different. I have done the research, prior to asking each question (hence the content) and I am genuinely stuck hence me asking these questions

Comment: Just this: don't cross-post, and ask one question at a time

Comment: Cereal - the word "Android" is utterly irrelevant to these questions (with the possible exception of the SQLite angle as discussed by Tom) - I think you need to edit your questions to remove that restriction, otherwise these are not the best of questions, and may be downvoted or closed (possibly as dupes of more general case questions)

Comment: The focus of my questions are the impact each of the vulnerabilities have upon the Android O.S. So when coding in Android, I can keep my eye out for issues which may lead to such vulnerabilities being utilized by attackers

Comment: Cereal - please **do not** delete and recreate questions!

Comment: XSS and SQL Injection are different topics, schroeder. For example our app has a separate backend, so SQL injection is not something the Android app needs to be concerned with. Just because two questions are worded similarly does not mean they should be combined. And to respond to the comment by @rory-alsop ... the word 'Android' is **not** irrelevant here. Since Android app's use their own programming language, they are potentially vulnerable to unique XSS attacks. For example, I (a database developer) am looking for ways to sanitize user input to avoid _android-specific_ XSS.

Comment: Mac - yes we know they are different topics, and android has specific issues, but these questions are badly worded and if you re-read you will see the problems.

Answer (score 1):

The specific example is not Cross Site Scripting, it is Cross App Scripting. With a specially crafted intent, an Android app could force another app (Chrome in this example) to execute some script in its (Chrome's) context.

This could abuse some privacy and authentication mechanisms. If I am not missing something, this vulnerability (fixed in Chrome quite a while ago) allowed a malicious app to hijack an opened web session with the user's bank and approve money transfer.

This is a bit of exaggeration, normal banking Web sites are protected from such attacks: they require user confirmation (i.e. re-enter password) to complete any sensitive operation.

The problem with Chrome was that it allowed a 3rd party app to impersonate itself via intent extra, and did not perform enough validation. This was not a security hole in the Android OS, and not an exploit that could be statistically used against random apps on your device, to find one that was not protected.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, it's due to poor implementation of `webview`. For an instance, `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` method on the WebSettings for a WebView shall trigger to a cross site scripting. It depends on the logic tier if the input is being stored & hence persistent XSS or it reflects.

[image]

Webview older than 4.2 when you Enable javascript for it shall always remain vulnerable to XSS unless the developer adds the `JavascriptInterface` annotation to any method that the developer wants available to the JavaScript. For applications running Android 4.2 - all public methods that are annotated with JavascriptInterface can be accessed from JavaScript.

Other variants of `Webview` might be something like this:

`this.webView.loadUrl("javascript:setContent(" + JSONObject.quote(this.content) + "," + i + ")");`

As you can see, the code used the same method (webView.loadUrl) for sending data to the HTML-part of the application. This too triggers XSS. Webview is mostly responsible for XSS on Android.

Answer (score -2):

You are correct that in general, a XSS attack is more a server level attack. Someone fills in a form or posts data to a server, the server accepts that data and fails to sanitise it. The data is tored, potentially with embedded javascript or redirects or links to remote objects with malicious payloads. Someone else visits the site and retrieves the data which as bee posted and the browser interprets the literal data, running the javascript, retrieving the linked object with malicious payload etc.

So, how does this apply to android when your android is usually not a server? In general it can be an issue because many apps use the same technology to render the content - essentially, html, javascript etc. So, if you have a message app and it just accepts an incoming message without doing any sanitising of the data, any javascript or links to embeded objects with malicious payloads will be processed just like in a browser, essentially a XSS attack.

Comment: Imho, XSS is more towards client side attack rather than server side. It takes advantages of the libraries which is responsible or the render. Other info is correct while I doubt the first part. Mostly in android it's `webview` which's responsible?